# Change html format with onclick into asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

How Do i put this html with onclick

```
 <a href="#" onClick="addInput()"><img src="..\common_pic\add.gif" /></a>
```

into

```
response.Write "<td align='left'><img src=""..\common_pic\add.gif"" border=0><input type='text' value='" & adoRecordset("production_unit") & "'name='production_unit' size='10'><img src=""..\common_pic\delete.gif"" border=0></td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this as your form:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <label>Initial label</label>
    <input class="target" type="text" value="Initial value" /><br />
</form>
<a onclick="addFunction()">Add new input</a>
```

And this is a mock of `addFunction()` code to do this:

```
function addFunction() {
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.type = "text";
   document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(input);
}
```

Comment: This is pure js now. Try to check!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to add that anchor tag to the image, you could try this :

```
response.Write "<td align='left'><a href=""#"" onClick=""addInput()""><img src=""..\common_pic\add.gif"" border=0>" & adoRecordset("production_unit") & "</a><img src=""..\common_pic\delete.gif"" border=0></td>"
```